# Creating a score that will go up every time a correct answer is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a quiz created using HTML, CSS, and javascript.  I am trying to add a score but when I add to it when it goes to the next question then it either adds 4 each time or does not add.  Any help appreciated

Javascript

> ```
> const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
> const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
> const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
> const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
> const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
> var score = 0
> score = Number(score)
> let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex
>
> startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
> nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
>   currentQuestionIndex++
>   setNextQuestion()
> })
>
> function startGame() {
>   startButton.classList.add('hide')
>   shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
>   currentQuestionIndex = 0
>   questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
>   setNextQuestion()
> }
>
> function setNextQuestion() {
>   resetState()
>   showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
> }
>
> function showQuestion(question) {
>   questionElement.innerText = question.question
>   question.answers.forEach(answer => {
>     const button = document.createElement('button')
>     button.innerText = answer.text
>     button.classList.add('btn')
>     if (answer.correct) {
>       //button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
>       answer.correct = Boolean(answer.correct)
>       button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
>
>    
>       //mainbox .body.correct
>       //$("mainbox").css("background-color","green");
>     }
>     button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
>     answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
>
>   })
> }
>
> function resetState() {
>   clearStatusClass(document.body)
>   nextButton.classList.add('hide')
>   while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
>     answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
>
>   }
>
> }
>
> function selectAnswer(e) {
>   const selectedButton = e.target
>   const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
>   setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
>   Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
>     setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
>
>
>
>   })
>   if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
>     nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
>   } else {
>     startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
>     startButton.classList.remove('hide')
>     window.alert("You have scored "+ score)
>     score = 0;
>     score = Number(score);
>
>   }
> }
>
> function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
>   clearStatusClass(element)
>   if (correct) {
>     element.classList.add('correct')
>
>
>
>
>   } else {
>     element.classList.add('wrong')
>   }
> }
>
> function clearStatusClass(element) {
>   element.classList.remove('correct')
>   element.classList.remove('wrong')
> }
>
> const questions = [
>   {
>     question: 'which is non-price factor?',
>     answers: [
>       { text: 'income', correct: true },
>       { text: 'price ', correct: false }
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     question: 'which is merit good?',
>     answers: [
>       { text: 'cigarette', correct: false },
>       { text: 'junk food ', correct: false },
>       { text: 'healthcare', correct: true },
>       { text: 'gambling', correct: false }
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     question: 'which one is not the type of market failure?',
>     answers: [
>       { text: 'monopoly market', correct: false },
>       { text: 'oligopoly market', correct: true },
>       { text: 'demerit goods', correct: false },
>       { text: 'negative externality', correct: false }
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     question: 'Total profit = total revenue - total cost?',
>     answers: [
>       { text: 'flase', correct: false },
>       { text: 'true', correct: true }
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```

Style Sheet

> ```
> #topbox{
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 70px;
>     background-color: rgb(146, 182, 214);
>  }
>  u1  {
>      list-style-type: none ;
>      margin : 0px ;
>      padding : 0 ;
>      overflow : hidden;
>      background-color: rgb(153, 197, 218);
> }
> li  {
>     float: left;
>  }
>  li a  {
>     display:inline-block;
>      padding: 20px;
>      border: 1px solid rgb(243, 240, 240);
>      background-color: rgb(153, 197, 218);
>      color: white;
>      text-align:center;
>      position:relative;
>      padding-bottom: 20px;
>      font-size: 20pt;
>
>  }
>  #medianbox{
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 73px;
>     background-color:rgb(153, 197, 218) ;
>  }
>  #mainbox{
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
>     background-color: rgb(146, 182, 214);
>
>  }
>
> *, *::before, *::after {
> box-sizing: border-box;
> font-family: Gotham Rounded;   }
>   .root {
> --hue-neutral: 200;
> --hue-wrong: 0;
> --hue-correct: 145;   }
>   .body {
> --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
> padding: 10000px;
> margin: 0;
> display: flex;
> width: 100vw;
> height: 100vh;
> justify-content: center;
> align-items: center;
> background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 20%);   }
>   .body.correct {
> hue: var(--hue-correct);   }
>   .body.wrong {
> --hue: var(--hue-wrong);   }
>   .container {
> width: 800px;
> max-width: 80%;
> background-color: white;
> border-radius: 5px;
> padding: 10px;
> box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;   }
> ```
>
> .btn-grid {
> display: grid;
> grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
> gap: 10px;
> margin: 20px 0;
> Color: blue;   }
>
> .btn {
> --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
> border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);   }
> .btn:hover {
> border-color: black;   }
> .btn.correct {
> --hue: var(--hue-correct);
> color: green;   }
> .btn.wrong {
> --hue: var(--hue-wrong);   }
> .start-btn, .next-btn {
> font-size: 1.5rem;
> font-weight: bold;
> padding: 10px 20px;   }
> .controls {
> display: flex;
> justify-content: center;
> align-items: center;   }
> .hide {
> display: flex;   }
>
> .p1 {
> font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
> font-size: 26pt;
> }

HTML

Quiz App
    
    
        
            BBS economic

definition

test

resource

community

search

me
        
         
        
        
          
                
                Question
                
                    Answer 1
                    Answer 2
                    Answer 3
                    Answer 4
                
                
                
                Start
                Next

Answer (score 3):

Consider this, If you're just creating a simple Quiz for practice.

```js
var score_card = document.getElementById('score');
var score_no = 0;
function Calculate(){
  if (document.getElementById('Q1sol3').checked == true){
    score_no+=1
  }
  if (document.getElementById('Q2sol4').checked == true){
    score_no+=1
  }
score_card.innerHTML = score_no;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span>SCORE: <span id="score">0</span></span>
  <br>
  <section>
    <div id="Q1">
      <span>What is your Fav Tag?</span><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="Q1sol1">
        <label for="Q1sol1">Body</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="Q1sol2">
        <label for="Q1sol2">Head</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="Q1sol3">
        <label for="Q1sol3">DIV</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="Q1sol4">
        <label for="Q1sol4">HTML</label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Q2">
      <span>What is your Fav attribute?</span><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2sol1">
        <label for="Q2sol1">src</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2sol2">
        <label for="Q2sol2">href</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2sol3">
        <label for="Q2sol3">style</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2sol4">
        <label for="Q2sol4">id</label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="btn" onClick="Calculate()" style="background:green; color:white; padding:3px;" value="Submit">
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```